# Coding a self association in UML diagram?

Tags: c++, uml

If I have a UML Class called Draw and it has an association to itself like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yifQN0p.png]

How can I create a getter and setter for this in the same class? Here is my shot at it:

```
#ifndef CDRAWABLE_H
#define CDRAWABLE_H
#include <list>

class CDrawable {
public:
    virtual ~CDrawable();

    void SetParent(CDrawable *mParent);
    CDrawable *GetParent() const;

private:
    //! \brief Default Constructor (Disabled)
    CDrawable();
    //! \brief Copy Constructor (Disabled)
    CDrawable(const CActor &);
    //! \brief Assignment Operator (Disabled)
    CDrawable &operator=(const CDrawable &);

    //! The parent of the drawable
    CDrawable *mParent;

    //! List of children of the drawable
    std::list<CDrawable *> mChildren;
```

And for my .cpp:

```
#include "wx/prec.h"
#include "CDrawable.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


CDrawable::~CDrawable() 
{
}

void CDrawable::SetParent(CDrawable *mParent)
{
    this->mParent = mParent;
}

CDrawable *CDrawable::GetParent()
{
    return mParent;
}
```

I've omitted some functions in the code to make it less lengthy.

EDIT: Here is the error I get on compiling:

```
CDrawable.cpp:153:12: error: prototype for ‘CDrawable* CDrawable::GetParent()’ does not match any in class ‘CDrawable’
CDrawable.h:25:16: error: candidate is: CDrawable* CDrawable::GetParent() const
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't your GetParent implementation look like this? Yours does not match what's in the header.

```
const CDrawable *CDrawable::GetParent() const
{
    return mParent;
}
```